# Strange pipe buffering

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

I have a file full of file numbers (starting from 0)

```
$ cat in.del
0
1
2
....
```

Could anybody explain what happens here and where does buffering take place other than in the pipe? To my understanding both `head's` fileno(stdin) must look directly into the pipe's read end

```
$ cat in.del | ( head -n1 ; head -n1 )
0
60
```

How the following code differs from the above one?

```
$ cat in.del | ( head -n10 ; head -n10 )
0
1
...
8
9
60
1861 # O_o
1862
1863
...
1868
1869
```

This works as expected and shows that `head` itself doesn't read more bytes than it actually writes to its' `stdout`:

```
$ ( head -n10 ; head -n10 ) < ./in.del
0
1
...
9
10
11
...
18
19
```

Obviously there is something related to pipe happening

**Update**

OS:Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Bash: version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**Update 2**
As an addition to the fantastic answer by @Barmar, [more on stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

Comment: On my Mac, the last example works the same as the second example. But on Debian Linux I get the same results as you.

Comment: @Barmar, updated the question with the system info. Also, I confirm the same behaviour you describe on Mac (last example gives same output as the second one), though, different line numbers outputed

Comment: I stumbled on this question because i had a similar problem. I needed the pipe support for my script using `variable=$(head -n 1)`. The workaround i found is using `read -r variable` instead. This seems also to work for the above examples `cat in.del | ( read -r line; echo $line ; read -r line ; echo $line )` in case somebody else (or me in the future) still needs the pipe support in their script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that stdio reads an entire buffer at a time from the pipe, and the buffer size on Linux is 8K.

Then `head` reads the first 10 lines out of the buffer, prints them, and exits.

The next `head` starts reading from the pipe where the last one left off, 8K bytes into the file.  It reads that line and the following 9 lines. The `60` that you see is the end of `1860`.

The reason why it works as expected in the last case is because `head` seeks to the end of the last line that it printed before it exits. Seeking doesn't work in a pipe, so this has no effect. But when `stdin` is an ordinary file, the seek works, and the next process starts from where the seek set the file position.

I see slightly different results on my Mac. Its buffer size is 64K, so the second `head` starts much later in the file. It also doesn't seek back to the end of the last printed line before exiting, so the version with file redirection works the same as piping.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Good catch on my experiment setup: once I found that this is due to bufferization, I should have changed line numbers to something like `^<line_number>$` and would've seen that `60` is not for line number `60`

Comment: Yeah, it's really confusing in the first test. In the second test, you can see that the next line is `1861`, and the line before that should be `1860`.

Comment: BTW, the word is "buffering", not "bufferization".